# Pass variables in url path to fetch GET request

Tags: javascript, url, path, get, fetch

I have this fetch request below, and variables data_type and data_subtype. I want to pass the value of data_type and data_subtype in the place of :type and :subtype respectively, without actually writing the variable values in there.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/feature/type/:type/subtype/:subtype,{
    method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {
        console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: So, you are asking us how to concatenate strings together in JS?

Comment: Thanks @blex!
I understood your point, a simple concatenation worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with the variable values in the URL.
eg.

```
const data_type = 'data Type' 
const data_subtype = 'data subtype
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/feature/type/${data_type}/subtype/${data_subtype}`,{
    method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {
        console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @junkie, this method also worked.

Answer (score 0):

as expanding the @junkie answer, you should put your url request in string literal so where you can use variables which will conditionaly replace the values without actually writing values in there, so just define and replace them.